# i want to print smallest number in array , i got error

Tags: java

how are you guys

i have question :

Write a method that accepts an array of integers and returns the smallest value in the list.

i have error in my code , what's the problem?

```
package homework;
```

public class Question44 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    System.out.println(min);
}

public static int smallestNumber(int numbers[]) {

    int min = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (min > numbers[i]) {
            min = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to actually call the method.

Answer (score 0):

your logic is correct but add int min=smallestNumber(numbers); inside main method.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'min' in the main method is out of scope.
And you have to call the smallestNumber method for the correct answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.